# Why can't I log into my minecraft account

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I paid for a minecraft account and everything but when I try to log in it says that I don't have a username. Is it an email or an email that you've made just for this account?

Comment: Did you mean to tag this with Steam?  Minecraft is not avaiable on Steam.

Comment: No I didn't sorry!

Comment: No problem!  Another question: did you get an account activation email when you registered your account?  You probably have to confirm it.

Comment: Yes I did but it never asked me for an username so when I try to log in it doesn't allow me.

Comment: Have you tried signing in here with your email and password: https://minecraft.net/store/minecraft  Try where it says 'already have a mojang account'.  Or try logging in on the main login page, and using your email as your username: https://minecraft.net/login

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work either D: It made it like I didn't pay or anyhting

Comment: Have you contacted Mojang support about this?

Answer (score 6):

If you have just bought Minecraft, you account will be a Mojang account. This means that 
instead of using your username (ex: player1234).
[image]

In the username field, you will use your email: (eg: player1234@xyz.com).

[image]

Source: https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/823771-error-logging-in-with-a-mojang-account

> When logging into Minecraft with a Mojang account (or a migrated Minecraft account), please be sure to use your email address, not your username, and Mojang account password

Comment: If you fix up some grammar issues, and add a source, this will be ready to go,

Comment: @ShadowZorgon Please point out these issues. But, I will add a source

Comment: @yayestechlab the only improvement I would suggest is using quote formatting `> text here` rather than code blocks `    text here` for quotations next time.

Comment: Sorry, the grammar mistake i thought it was was the separation between the images and the text.

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft Login servers could be down (they aren't at the moment of this post, you can always check at [help.mojang.com](http://help.mojang.com))

You could be using the wrong username. If you created your minecraft account after a certain time (after they changed logging in with your username to logging in with your email address) then you will need to login with you email address and whatever password you created when you created your account. "To create a username, register a Mojang account at account.mojang.com. After you are logged in, you can purchase a Minecraft account. You will be sent an email with a redemption link, which you can click to complete this process. If you do not click the redemption link, a green box will appear on your Mojang profile, prompting you to choose a new username, or import a previously-registered one." (https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/928638)   That could also be the problem, that you haven't redeemed your purchase and/or selected a username. You should check your email and see if you need to still create your username.

You do NOT need to migrate your minecraft account to a mojang account if you do not wish to, although a Mojang account will have more features, and you are required to use a mojang account if your account was created after they decided that.

Answer (score 0):

It says on the log in screen to type in your username or e-mail address, 
It also says "Which do I use" (as a link)

If you do not know which one to use you should lick on the link.
It will then bring you to an instructional website about how to log in to Mojang.